# How can I use template-methods in groovy-servlet with out compile?

Tags: servlets, groovy, template-method-pattern

I have a groovy-servlet named query1_action.groovy as:

```
String sql = "...";
String sql_count = "...";

try {
    def ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env");
    def datasource = ctx.lookup("jdbc/tlink");
    def executer = Sql.newInstance(datasource);
    def rows = executer.rows(sql);
    def gson = new com.google.gson.GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
    def result = gson.toJson(rows);

    def rows_count = executer.firstRow(sql_count).num;
    int page_count = (rows_count+page_size-1)/page_size;
    out << """{"rs": "1", "rows": ${result}, "rows_count": ${rows_count}, "page": {"page_size": ${page_size}, "page_count": ${page_count}, "pn": ${p.pn}}}""";
} catch(Exception e) {
    context.log("query1_action.groovy === ${e}");
    out << '{"rs": "0"}';
}
```

I have query1_action.groovy, query2_action.groovy, and so on, all the try-catch parts are the same.

And I want to make a template-methods by this part.

I do not know how to extends some base class in this case, when I extends class, groovy servlet can not run.

How to make that please?